# Access WC() class of Woocommerce from anywhere

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

while I develop my website, I try to display the content of WC Session like this :

```
$datas = WC()->session->get('datas'); var_dump($datas);
```

I can see all my datas stored.

But when I submit my form, and use `admin_post` action, I can't use `WC()`.. (Weird because in ajax, It works)
Well I searched and I tried :

```
$session = new WC_Session_Handler();
$session_data = $session->get_session_data();
var_dump($session_data);
```

But no datas here.. How can I access `WC()` function ?

I need for session but also to add to cart or empty cart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the way to use it in admin

Apparently, you can't access WC from admin because it's only loaded on front end.

To use it in admin, you have to include it with `WC()->frontend_includes();`

I achieve this like that :

```
WC()->frontend_includes();
WC()->session = new WC_Session_Handler();
WC()->session->init();
```

Comment: Nice answer… You should use before this IF statement  `if ( ! isset(WC()->session) )`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks ! But it's weird, when I set session from admin, I can't access it from front end now

Comment: You should may ask a new question with a complete testable example, as with the provided code and information from your question, people can really help you.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65552426/pass-woocommerce-session-from-admin-to-front-end