# Pass Woocommerce Session from admin to front-end

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I try to pass datas from admin to front like :

```
WC()->frontend_includes();
WC()->session = new WC_Session_Handler();

WC()->session->set('datas', array(
 '_email' => "email_here"
));
```

And retrieve them in front. For example here :

```
function action_woocommerce_before_checkout_form($wccm_autocreate_account)
{
    $datas = WC()->session->get('datas');
    var_dump($datas);
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'action_woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 10, 1);
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_contents', 'action_woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 10, 1);
```

When I var_dump $datas in admin, I see my values but not on front

Comment: Thinking about deeply make things clear: `WC_Session` is used for "User session" on front end. So if you set a `WC_Session` in backend, it is not related to a specific user (or/and to a user cookie), so that's why you can't set a WooCommerce session in backend and retrieve it in front end (I think)…